# xinput changing id of touchpad after restart

Tags: linux, xorg

Running custom keyboard and touchpad modifications, I want to to activate 2 finger scrolling using:

```
xinput --set-prop id "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 1
```

where id is the device id found using

```
xinput --list
```

The id whoever changes after restart. Preferably one would use a batch script to automate finding the id and setting the preference.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: What are you talking about? Elitism? Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. If you want to tinker with your hardware then go to [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a bash script

```
idd=$(xinput --list | grep 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad' | awk '{print $6}'| cut -d'=' -f2)

xinput --set-prop $idd "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 1
```

First list xinput and find the touchpad controller, then find the entry that corresponds to the id, in this case the 6th string. Further cut the id=... from the ouput.

This will find out the devices id and set 2 finger scrolling accordingly.
Will work for other devices as well.

Comment: Or just use the device name as `id`: `xinput set-prop 'SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad' 'Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling' 1 1`

Answer (score 4):

Update: This worked for me, just add Pointer or Keyboard as a prefix to the device name.

LINUX:~$ xinput --set-prop "Logitech MX Master 2S" 157 5 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 1

Warning: There are multiple devices matching 'Logitech MX Master 2S'.
To ensure the correct one is selected, please use the device ID, or prefix the
device name with 'pointer:' or 'keyboard:' as appropriate.

unable to find device pointer

#Solution

LINUX:~$ xinput --set-prop "pointer:Logitech MX Master 2S" 157 5 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 1